# Repo in VS Code disappeared

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I don't know much about git but I've been using it with my rust project to learn more about it.

When trying to commit after using git for a couple of months, I  suddenly got an error `Couldn't set refs/heads/`.

The answer I found when looking it up is the command `echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD`

But when I ran it the repo in the version control tab of VSCode disappeared.

I tried looking it up, running `git init` again but it doesn't seem to do anything. Tried `git status` but it says `fatal: not a git repository` even when running the command inside the .git folder

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Was your branch actually called `master` when things were still working? I do not understand the command you used, but if it was called differently then `refs/heads/master` should be replaced by that for sure

Comment: My branch was called `main` and when I wrote the command I changed it to `refs/heads/main`. Here it's master because I copied it from the answer I found and I thought probably more people use master instead of main

Comment: I don't know how Visual Studio Code might affect things, but usually, this kind of problem occurs when you have told your own computer to store your Git repository in a cloud-synced folder. This *works*, initially. But eventually the syncing software breaks the repository, sometimes subtly (stuff stops working right) or sometimes grossly (`fatal: not a git repository`). The only real cure is "don't do that".

Comment: @torek you might be right! Didn't even think that the folder being in Dropbox could break it, I'll check on it later